# What can I add to current query for a responsive top navigation?

Tags: css, nav, responsive

http://pixphoriad.net

This is my first shot at a semi-responsive design. I found a smooth nav code (I copy pasta queries as I don't know A LOT about them), but unfortunately its based on a width being under 680px to condense into the menu button, and most smart phones are very high res (I'm assuming this is why it's not functioning on my S7). Is there something simple I can add to this query or change about it to have it function a bit better? I'd prefer to keep this part of my code fairly simple.

```
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none; 
  }

  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }

  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }

  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }

  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: Resolution doesn't really matter nowadays, since mobiles can have bigger resolution than desktop. So you should check whether the user is on mobile or not and apply certain styles. There are various ways to do that.

Comment: I know. That's what I'm asking for. What do I need, to "check" if the user is on mobile or not?

Comment: Use javascript and check the useragent.

Comment: Fixed on my own, thanks anyways